# How to show a different sender for messages sent through twilio

Tags: java, twilio

My app uses Twilio to send SMS. When a user wants to invite a friend to my app, my server uses Twilio to send the message. But right now my twilio phone number is in the sender field that the recipient sees. How do I change that number to be the phone number of the user who invited the friend?

- User X wants to invite user Y to start using my app
- When user Y gets the message, the sender should appear to be user X (phone number)
- but right now, the sender appears as my own Twilio number.

So restating again: How do I get the displayed sender to be the phone number of user X? Assume of course I already have the number and need to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use phone numbers or short codes purchased from Twilio.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

> Parameter "From": A Twilio phone number enabled for the type of message you wish to send. Only phone numbers or short codes purchased from Twilio work here; you cannot (for example) spoof messages from your own cell phone number.

Or verify a phone number.
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-i-use-a-non-twilio-number-as-the-caller-id-for-outgoing-calls

> ...verify the number with Twilio. Verification takes just a few seconds, and proves to us that you have authority to use the phone number.

Comment: I understand that. What I want is to be able to **display** a different sender phone number to the recipient.

Comment: this would be a sort of masking, as I am sending the message on behalf of someone else -- a user.

Comment: You can verify a phone number and have it display as the sender: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-i-use-a-non-twilio-number-as-the-caller-id-for-outgoing-calls